# Can every implication $∀x, p(x)→q(x)$ be read as "every $p(x)$, $q(x)$" or "All $p(x)$, are $q(x)$"..

Tags: logic, soft-question, terminology, first-order-logic

For example, if I say "all dogs are animals" I can symbolize this as "∀x, If $x$ is a dog, then $x$ is an animal", or if I say "every person likes ice cream", I can symbolize it as "∀x, if $x$ is a person, then $x$ likes ice cream". So, can every implication be read like "all $p(x)$, is/are/likes.. $q(x)$"?

Another example: "let $(S,≼)$ be a partially ordered set. If $S$ is well-ordered, then $S$ is totally ordered" can I read this theorem as "every well ordered poset is totally ordered"? which is a little less confusing to understand

Thank you!

Comment: How could you read, say, "$0=1\rightarrow0=0$" that way?

Comment: It seems to me that you are focusing on this type of implication :
$$\forall x. x \in A \implies x\in B$$

which says that $A \subseteq B,$ where $A,B$ are sets.

Comment: NO.............

Comment: @MarkS. yeah of course not every sentence written in that way has a "normal" meaning in English, some would just make sentences more confusing, you could read that as "all equalities of the form 0=1 imply 0=0" I guess, but it's just weird

Comment: @RiccardoAllegrone No I didn't think about that definition in particular, I was saying in general, that could be read for example as "every element that is in A is also in B" which is again what I said

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA OK...…….. but why?

Comment: See first comment above; alternatively: "if Socrates is a man, then Socrates is mortal".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA but that does not have the form that i'm talking about, I added details to my question, the implication needs to have a universal quantifier, "if Socrates is a man, then Socrates is mortal" does not have the same form as "all/every -- is/has/do ---"